# looping through F# record like Javascript object

Tags: f#

In javascript, I can access every property of an object with a simple for loop as follows

```js
var myObj = {x:1, y:2};
var i, sum=0;
for(i in myObj) sum = sum + myObj[i];
```

I am wondering if I can do similar thing with F#.

```
type MyObj = {x:int; y:int}
let myObj = {x=1; y=2}
let allValues:seq<int> = allPropertyValuesIn myObj //How do I implement allPropertyValuesIn 
let sum = allValues |> Seq.fold (+) 0
```

Thank you for your input

**Edit to clarify why I want to do such thing**
I am working on an XML file generator. The input is rows read from Database, and the xsd is predefined.

Lets say I have a "Product" Element needs to be generated and depending on the business rule, there could be 200 Children element under product some are required, some are optional. Following the advise from [this excellent blog](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-for-correctness/), I have had my first (very rough) design for product record:

```
1.    type Product{ Price:Money; Name:Name; FactoryLocation:Address option ... }
2.    let product = {Price = Money(1.5); Name = Name ("Joe Tooth Paste"); ... }
3.    let child1 = createEl ("Price", product.Price)
   ..
203.  let allChildren = child1
                        ::child2
                        ::child3
                        ..
                        ::[]
404.  let prodctEl = createElWithCildren ("Product", allChildren)
```

This is very tedious and un-succinct. There HAS to be a better way to do such thing in F#. I am not very kin on the reflection idea either.

Are there any other approaches or I am just doing it wrong?

Comment: This is possible with reflection, but I don't think a fast, type safe alternative exists.

Comment: "Edit to clarify why..." your problem has changed a lot :/ if you want automate over childs structure you must NORMALIZE your childs structure (your 200 childs structure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type MyObj = {x:int; y:int}
let myObj = {x=1; y=2}
let allValues = FSharpType.GetRecordFields (myObj.GetType())
let sum =
    allValues
    |> Seq.fold
        (fun s t -> s + int(t.GetValue(myObj).ToString()))
        0
printfn "%d" sum
```

However, as John Palmer admonishes, there are not very many good reasons for doing something like this.

Comment: This is one of those good reasons though. Treating a struct/record like a map (the data structure, which is really what a struct is) is useful for getting the most out of your type checker in public interfaces. You can use a record to represent all possible parameters to a web api (including Option types where appropriate). Then behind the scenes, do something like this instead of writing a wall of member names to build the http payload. The wall-of-names approach is especially bad for maintainability.