# Where is the Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Typed module in F# 3

Tags: f#

I have asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976673/looping-through-f-record-like-javascript-object), and the answers I got was not to my satisfactory. Today, I ran into [this tutorial](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-dynamic-lookup.aspx) and thought it may be able to help my situation.

I copy/pasted the example code to Visual Studio, and found that

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Typed and
Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Raw
```

modules no longer existed.

Is there any replacement in F# 3?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial was written in 2008, so it precedes even F# 2.0 (which shipped in April 2010 as part of VS2010).

For F# 2.0 and 3.0, you only need to open one namespace ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370558.aspx)):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
```

The [Code Quotations (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx) article on MSDN has more information and code examples.